# How do I print the text between two strong tags without the tags in the output?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

I have a program that goes to a webpage and goes to the specific li, and when I print div.strong it prints the value between two strong tags as the output, when I just want the value.

```
    import bs4
    #uReq is our arbitrary shorthand for urllib.request
    import urllib
    from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

    #The URL we plan to use
    my_url = 'https://www.newegg.com/'
    Client = uReq(my_url)
    html_page = Client.read()
    Client.close()
    page_soup = soup(html_page, "html.parser")
    itemContainers = page_soup.findAll("div", {"class":"item- 
    container"})
    OverallContainer = itemContainers[0]
    divWithInfo = itemContainers[0].find("li", "price-current")
    print(divWithInfo.strong)
```

Comment: This is sort of off topic, but are you scraping NewEgg? I'm just interested

Comment: Yes i am! Im following a web scraping tutorial on youtube. How did you know?

Comment: What is `itemContainers`? Please provide a complete example, which includes information about what library you're actually using and which can be run by someone trying to help.

Comment: I just tried to make a scraper for NewEgg yesterday and I recognized that as the price of an item.

Comment: Well do you happen to know how I can get the price without the tags?

Comment: I couldn't get it to work because I think NewEgg renders some of the code with JS which makes it impossible to retrieve with BS4

Comment: You are grabbing and printing the element with `<strong>` tags with `print(divWithInfo.strong)` Since you want only the text, include `.text`. so change that last line to `print(divWithInfo.strong.text) `